# Apache don't have full permission

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, webmin

I setup local server on ubuntu, install webmin to have access from desk, install apache etc. And at the end I install joomla as I'm building local use erp system.

But it looks like Apache (or php I don't know) don't have some permission as not allowing to write files, move files etc. when I try to install any plugin/module I get info that I can't "move file".

I try to `chown` whole directory to `www-date` user/group but I can't. 
How to allow apache to write files so I can use it as normal web server?

Comment: Did you mean user: `www-data`? and which directory are you talking about? Please post the full error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such user as `www-date` and it should be `www-data`.

Secondly, there are a few directory/file ownership and permissions you need to set, for joomla to work. You can have a look at a how-to here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Joomla

Here are the relevant part for you:

> Next the files need to be moved and the ownership changed
>
> ```
> cd ..
> sudo mv joomla /var/www/
> cd /var/www/joomla
> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
>
> Change Permissions
>
> cd /var/www/joomla/
> sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
> sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
> ```

In the example `/var/www/joomla` is the joomla installation directory. You will need to adjust the file/directory ownership and permission for your installation as stated above.

Comment: reg www-date it was mistyping and yes it's www-data

but much more important is that I try to work with J3.5 and this was reason for my problems. I install 3.4.8 version and this works with no problems